# Can Sparseimage be mounted in linux?

Tags: linux, mount, disk-image

I have a .sparseimage file that I am trying to mount on Linux. I have tried mounting with the hfs and hfsplus filesystem specified but no luck. Has anyone done this before? I have used the below commands with no luck. I am able to mount the sparseimage on my macbook pro. I am using Debian 7.

```
sudo mount -t hfs /image/to/mount /mount/location
sudo mount -t hfsplus /image/to/mount /mount/location
```

Comment: Please include the exact commands you ran, the error messages (if any) you received, indicate if you know that the image is OK (can it be mounted on another system?), the Linux distribution you are using (probably irrelevant but you ever know) etc. The more information you give us, the likelier it is we'll be able to help you.

Comment: Can you run the `file` command on the .sparseimage file?

Comment: https://github.com/torarnv/sparsebundlefs from http://superuser.com/questions/306497/can-linux-mount-a-normal-time-machine-sparse-bundle-disk-image-directory

Comment: Sami's comment is probably the way to go, but in any case, to mount an image (not a drive) you need the `-o loop` option.

Comment: Yeah it's supported, contrary to using sparse-file-backed swap.

Comment: @SamiLaine Uh... that seems to be for a sparse*bundle*, not a sparse*image*.